# Using SQL Compact 4 in Visual C# 2010 express

Tags: sql-server-ce-4, visual-c#-express-2010

It is posible to use SQL Server Compact 4 inside Visual C# 2010 Express? I tried reinstall it many times (with Web Platform Installer and without it) but I still cannot see option for SQL Compct 4 in Data Source selection window.

[image: Visual C# 2010 Express]

But what is strange, I can see it in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

[image: Visual Web Developer 2010 Express]

Is there any way how I can access to version 4 from Visual C# 2010 Express?

Comment: It is a beta (?) release and was tied to ASP.NET and IIS express. Maybe you can make (start) a Class Lib in WebDev containing your DAL.

Comment: I have installed VS C# SP1 express, SQL CE 4 and VS 2010 Tools for SQL CE 4 and I still have the same issue. I should add VS 2010 Tools for SQL CE 4 fails to install it wont recognise VS c# 2010 Express SP1 as SP1 even though its stated in the about dialogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 4.0 only shows for Web Projects, not for desktop projects - as stated here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/03/15/sql-server-compact-4-0-tooling-support-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-visual-web-developer-express-2010-sp1.aspx